# Keras custom optimizer change parameters in batches

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I want to custom my own optimizer which will change the learning rate at the end of each batch in keras. At first, I build a custom callback:

```
class custom_callback(Callback):
  def __init__(self,lr):
    super(op_callback, self).__init__()
    self.lr=lr

  def on_batch_end(self,batch,logs={}):
    sgd = SGD(lr=batch*self.lr)
    self.model.compile(optimizer=sgd,loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And then, I copy the SGD optimizer code from [doc](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py). Because I want to make sure the learning rate is changed, so I print the learning rate in `get_update` function.

```
def get_updates(self, loss, params):
    print(self.lr)
    ...
```

But it prints the learning rate only once. I've found that the `get_update` function will be called only at the beginning of build the computation graph. But I still do not understand why it won't print anything even I re-initialize the SGD instance. How can I change the parameters at the end of batches in optimizer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for `LearningRateScheduler` it seems a minimal way to achieve what you want is the following (it did not check how often `get_update` is called, I'm not even sure if it should be executed on every batch, in any case this callback definitely does adjust the learning rate):

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import Callback

class BatchLearningRateScheduler(Callback):
    def __init__(self, lr):
        super().__init__()
        self.lr = lr

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        lr = batch * self.lr
        K.set_value(self.model.optimizer.lr, lr)
```